# Android application programming with Netbeans

Tags: java, android, netbeans

Hello I am new to the topic of Android App programming and wanted to ask if there are any good resources out there for learning to program Android Apps, possibly with Netbeans?

I already found some youtube videos about installing the sdk and so, but they don`t really explain the topic of Activities nor how the design works (I figured it is some kind of XML?) Also I am interested in how to do Database Connections.

Comment: It's much easier just to download the ADK directly from Google than go through the shoe-horning netbeans option.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would prefer programming in Netbeans over Eclipse or Android Studios?  As for Activities and layout, you'll have to learn about the Activity Lifecycles and layouts are done in XML.

Comment: I have voted to close this as it is not clear what is being questioned here, as far as I concern. Regarding resources on Activities, refer to this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html How to set up SDK and IDE: these are different issues. Please let's try to address one at a time.

Comment: maybe at least spelling Android correctly in the title?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Android development.

May I suggest `Eclipse`, another IDE **VERY** similar to Netbeans and also quite easy to install with this bundle: (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

You figured right, XML files are used to define the layout of each activity.

SQLiteDatabase is a light-weight database which is used with android applications.

Here are some really nice tutorials to get started:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

You can also do a simple google search for beginners tutorials for hundreds of other tutorials.

Comment: thanks for your answer, is there a reason why you would suggest Eclipse rather than Netbeans? This Tutorials are very useful! :)

Comment: @JakobAbfalter: The reason is eclipse has official support from google. Netbeans plugins are made by community, not the official android staff.

Comment: No differences in particular.  I used to develop with Netbeans ( not android ) and I do not see any difference.  I suggested it because you have a complete bundle ready for download on the link I provided and it is supported by google like @Celebes said